# Spacy trained model: input error dimension

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

here is where i load my model:

```
_model = r"C:\Users\evead\Desktop\spacy_model_config_03_15\model-best"
nlp = spacy.load(_model)


txt = "Below are my data loader and neural net. I have also included the output of my data loader when I retrieve a batch of data"

doc = nlp(txt)
```

here is the error I got

`but I got the following error:`
`Exception has occurred: RuntimeError`
`input must have 3 dimensions, got 2`
`File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\src\debug_entity.py", line 46, in <module>`
`doc = nlp(txt)`

Comment: Please show your complete code and error.

Comment: Don't put your error in an answer, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

here is my complete error:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER> python -m spacy evaluate C:\Users\evead\Desktop\spacy_model_config_03_15\model-best C:\Users\evead\Desktop\batchdata-3-15\train.spacy --output  C:\Users\evead\Desktop\batchdata-3-15\res.json
```

Using CPU

```
C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\torch\autocast_mode.py:141: UserWarning: User provided device_type of 'cuda', but CUDA is not available. Disabling
  warnings.warn('User provided device_type of \'cuda\', but CUDA is not available. Disabling')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evead\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\evead\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\_util.py", line 71, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 500, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\evaluate.py", line 42, in evaluate_cli
    evaluate(
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\evaluate.py", line 78, in evaluate
    scores = nlp.evaluate(dev_dataset)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 1415, in evaluate
    for eg, doc in zip(examples, docs):
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 1575, in pipe
    for doc in docs:
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 1598, in _pipe
    yield from proc.pipe(docs, **kwargs)
  File "spacy\pipeline\transition_parser.pyx", line 230, in pipe
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 1547, in minibatch
    batch = list(itertools.islice(items, int(batch_size)))
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 1598, in _pipe
    yield from proc.pipe(docs, **kwargs)
  File "spacy\pipeline\trainable_pipe.pyx", line 79, in pipe
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 1617, in raise_error
    raise e
  File "spacy\pipeline\trainable_pipe.pyx", line 75, in spacy.pipeline.trainable_pipe.TrainablePipe.pipe
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\tok2vec.py", line 125, in predict
    tokvecs = self.model.predict(docs)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py", line 315, in predict
    return self._func(self, X, is_train=False)[0]
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\chain.py", line 54, in forward
    Y, inc_layer_grad = layer(X, is_train=is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_array.py", line 40, in forward
    return _list_forward(cast(Model[List2d, List2d], model), Xseq, is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_array.py", line 76, in _list_forward
    Yf, get_dXf = layer(Xf, is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_padded.py", line 36, in forward
    Y, backprop = _array_forward(layer, cast(Floats3d, Xseq), is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_padded.py", line 76, in _array_forward
    Yp, get_dXp = layer(Xp, is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_padded.py", line 30, in forward
    Y, backprop = layer(Xseq, is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\pytorchwrapper.py", line 134, in forward
    Ytorch, torch_backprop = model.shims[0](Xtorch, is_train)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\shims\pytorch.py", line 56, in __call__
    return self.predict(inputs), lambda a: ...
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\thinc\shims\pytorch.py", line 66, in predict
    outputs = self._model(*inputs.args, **inputs.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 689, in forward
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 632, in check_forward_args
    self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
  File "C:\Users\evead\Desktop\Issam\PIXITREND-CLASSIFIER\Annotation-Training\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 201, in check_input
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2
```